# Proving the largest Hausdorff quotient is connected

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is a topological space with equivalence relation $\sim$ defined as: $x \sim y$ if for any $Y$ that is a Hausdorff space and any continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ we have that $f(x) = f(y)$. $X/\sim$ is called the largest Hausdorff quotient of $X$.

I now want to prove that $X$ is connected if and only if $X/\sim$ is connected.

I'm struggling with both implications because it's not given that $f$ is surjective.

I might want to use the following proposition (which I still should prove): If $Y$ is a Hausdorff space and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function, then $f$ can be factorized in the canonical projection map $\pi_H: X \rightarrow X_H$ and a unique continuous function $f_H: X_H \rightarrow Y$.

Comment: Have you proved that $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: @PaulFrost where do I need to use that $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: You do not need it for the connectedness-theorem. I just asked because you called $X_H$ the largest Hausdorff quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient map $\pi_H : X \to X_H  = X/\sim$ is a continuous surjection. Therefore if $X$ is connected, then $X_H$ is connected.

Now let $X$ be a non-connected space. Then there exists non-empty disjoint open $U, V \subset X$ such that $X = U \cup V$. Let $T$ be the space $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology (which is Hausdorff). The map $f : X \to T, f(x) = 0$ for $x \in U$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in V$ is a continuous surjection. By your proposition we have $f = f_H \circ \pi_H$, where $f_H : X_H \to T$ is continuous. Since $f$ is surjective, also $f_H$ must be surjective. The sets $U_H = f_H^{-1}(0)$ and $V_H = f_H^{-1}(1)$ are open, non-empty (recall $f_H$ surjective), disjoint and cover $X_H$. Thus $X_H$ is not connected.

Let us finally prove your proposition. So let $g : X  \to Z$ be a continuous map to a Hausdorff space $Z$. If $x \sim y$, then in particular $g(x) = g(y)$. Thus $g = g_H \circ \pi_H$ with a unique *function* $g_H : X_H \to Z$. The universal property of the quotient shows that $g_H$ is continuous.

Comment: Doesn't the universal property only hold for surjective functions? In any case, we've only seen it for surjections, so I think I still have prove that it hold for continuous instead of surjective?

Comment: It holds for all function. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology), section "Properties".

Comment: Is the proposition I wrote down not exactly the same as the universal property? How could I prove this property?

Comment: No, your proposition mixes two ingredients: 1. If $g : X  \to Z$ is a continuous map to a Hausdorff space $Z$, then $g = g_H \circ \pi_H$ with a unique *function* $g_H : X_H \to Z$. This is what I proved in my answer. 2. The universal property of the quotient (see the wikipedia article) which proves the continuity of $g_H$. Taking both ingredients together you obtain what we may call the universal property of the largest Hausdorff quotient of $X$.

Comment: Doesn't the universal also property also prove that there is a unique function $g_H$  *regardless* of anything being Hausdorff?

Comment: No. You must first **find** a function $g_H$ with $g = g_H \circ \pi_H$; then the universal property of the quotient shows that it is continuous. But to find $g_H$ you need to know that $Z$ is Hausdorff. See my answer.

Comment: I am confused. Your wikipedia link says [If some conditions are satisfied] *there exists a unique continuous map $f:X/\sim \rightarrow Z$ such that $g=f\circ q$.* So the universal property proves that there exists a map no? It certainly doesn't say what the map is, just that it exists

Comment: It says "Quotient maps $q : X → Y$ are characterized among surjective maps by the following property: if $Z$ is any topological space and $f : Y → Z$ is any function, then $f$ is continuous if and only if $f ∘ q$ is continuous." You need to **have** a function $f$ to apply it. Concerning quotients "The quotient space $X/∼$ together with the quotient map $q : X → X/∼$ is characterized by the following universal property: if $g : X → Z$ is a continuous map such that $a ∼ b$ implies $g (a) = g( b)$ for all $a , b ∈ X$, then there exists a unique continuous map $f : X/∼→ Z$ such that $g = f ∘ q$.

Comment: Thus you have to prove that $g(a) =g(b)$ for $a \sim b$, and this is what I have done using that $Z$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: We're mixing up the $f$ and $g$ here I think, my $f$ is the $g$ on the wiki and my $f_H$ is the $f$ there.

Comment: So in my notation: I choose a Hausdorff space $Y$ and a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow Y$. Then we can consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ as in my post. It is also given that $X_H = X / \sim$ is equipped with the quotient topology and that $\pi_H: X \rightarrow X_H$ is the canonical projction map. Then all conditions of the universal property are satisfied so we get that there exists a continuous function $f_H :X_H \rightarrow Y$.

Comment: With the universal property I'm referring to the second property listed on the wiki, it starts with *The quotient space $X/ \sim$ together with the quotient map...*